# Probability of being drawn multiple times with replacement

Tags: probability

I am taking the numbers 1 through 100 and placing them in a hat. I will be drawing 1 number at a time, then placing the number back in the hat. I will be doing this 63 different times.

I am needing to know the calculation for percentage odds/probability of drawing the same name x number of times.

So, I know the obvious answer is the odds of being drawn 1 time is 63 / 100 = 63% chance. But how do I calculate the odds of being drawn 2,3----63 times?

Thanks for the help

Comment: If you mean  a **particular** number being drawn $x$ times, use the binomial distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: Yes, what are the odds of a particular number being drawn 2,3, 4 times ect..      I took a look at that page and it is completely out of my league. What is the simplified version for just a name being drawn 2 and 3 times?

Answer (score 1):

Probability of being drawn on a single trial = $\frac1{100}= 0.01$

P(drawn $2$ times in $63$ trials) $= \binom{63}2\times0.01^2\times 0.99^{60} = 0.1058$

P(drawn $3$ times in $63$ trials) $= \binom{63}3\times0.01^3\times0.99^{59} = 0.0217$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, being that there are 100 names but we are only drawing 63 times, not 100 times, is this part of the equation an error(drawn 2 times in 100 trials)?

Comment: Adjusted as per above.